# Can access everything except my school domain

Tags: networking, dns

Everything has been working fine for me until this morning when I could not access everything from my school domain (anything with xyz.edu).
 I'm on Mac OX 10.9. 
 The hosts file looks OK to me:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
54 ::1             localhost
55 fe80::1%lo0 localhost
```

Preferences -> DNS looks normal:

```
208.67.222.222
```

Whenever I go to website, I see the message "**This webpage is not available Error code: ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID**". I could join the school wifi network but I just cannot access anything under my school domain.

I can run "**host website_name**" and get the IP address of the site but weird enough I cannot access the site on any browsers I have (Chrome, Firefox, Safari). I've also tried "**sudo dscacheutil -flushcache**" but nothing changed.

I'm really clueless how to fix this. Can someone please help?

Thanks,

Comment: Is your school domain `.local` by any chance?

Comment: no, Nikolay. It's .edu. In fact I have problem with a series of edu sites, including princeton.edu, gwu.edu, umd.edu, gmu.edu. Not all the .edu though, eg. harvard.edu works for me. It looks like the academy is abandoning me :)

Comment: I see. What happens if you try to access it using IP address, not hostname?

Comment: the same with accessing via IP address. I don't think my problem is with DNS because I can access other websites and I can run host command to obtain IP address. I guess the problem must be the site was added to some blocking list that is hidden somewhere. But I don't know exactly what it is and where it could be

Comment: OK. Could you try to ping those unavailable resources and let me know results? Also, try to do `wget` one of the problematic sites and post results.

Comment: `$ curl princeton.edu
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 128.112.128.81: Can't assign requested address`

Comment: ping requests time out. I've tried traceroute and got `traceroute: bind: Can't assign requested address`

Comment: [this answer on ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/a/80446/145512) might be related to your problem. Try to follow instructions given in this answer.

Comment: +1 I've just literally restarted my computer after flushing the route before seeing your comment. I found it through [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1550251). But thank you for the link. Please post it as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user [Cavver](https://serverfault.com/users/3353/cavver) explained [in his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/80446/145512) flushing the routing table (`route -n flush`) and recreating it again (by whatever procedure is typical for you) solves the problem.